# jQuery, PL/SQL and IE - can't include generated javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plsql

I have a very strange problem and I can't deal with it.
At some place in my html page I want to include a javascript which is automatically generated by pl/sql. Unfortunately, this don't work in IE6/7/8 (I don't know if the problem remains in newer IE's).
I get:

> 'script error jquery.min.js, character 0, line 0, code 0'

My html in pl/sql:

```
htp.p('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mypage.com:4449/schema/!package.scriptload?foo='||foo||'&bar='||bar||'"></script>');
```

At the moment, the scriptload procedure does nothing special:

```
procedure scriptload(name_array owa.vc_arr, value_array owa.vc_arr) is
  begin
    htp.p('<!--');
    htp.p('alert(''plsql javascript'');');
    /* something to do later*/
    htp.p('-->');
  end;
```

I'm very confused, because when I put a standalone script to my ftp and include it, it works without any problems. 
Indeed, I have !test.js file, that contains the same alert:

```
<!--
    alert('ftp javascript');
-->
```

i use this line to include it:

```
htp.p('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://myftp.com/folder/!test.js?foo='||foo||'&bar='||bar||'"></script>');
```

And it works in IE6,7,8. I don't have any more ideas, why. Could You help me? PS. I've tried $.getScript but this didn't help me.

Screenshot from MSScriptEditor that shows place of an error:
[Link to image](https://ankiety.uz.zgora.pl/rekr/error.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have quite some experience with mod_plsql but I cannot really understand what you are trying to do and there seems to be an indirection not really needed.

Why would your PL/SQL code use

```
htp.p('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mypage.com:4449/schema/!package.scriptload?foo='||foo||'&bar='||bar||'"></script>');
```

instead of simply invoking the procedure scriptload and dynamically generate the needed javascript code ?